# Spark: spark-submit won't take custom log4j.properties

Tags: logging, apache-spark, log4j

This could be possible duplicate of [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31856532/spark-unable-to-load-custom-log4j-properties-from-fat-jar-resources), but that was relevant to `Spark` `1.3/4`. I am using `1.5.2`.

I am packaging `log4j.properties` in my fat jar. It is showing different behavior in two scenarios. On ubuntu `machine 1`, I have spark in a user directory. On similar `machine 2`, I have it system installed. On  machine 2 a default `log4j.properties` is available at : `/etc/spark/conf/log4j.properties`.

On `machine 2`, the packaged `log4j.properties` in the fat-jar is not getting loaded, but it does on `machine 1`. I am using the same command on both machines:

```
spark-submit 
--master local[1]   
--class com.myCompany.myMainClass  myFat.jar
```

Based on [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/running-on-yarn.html), I am though able to do it forcefully by providing it from outside by:

```
spark-submit 
--master local[1]
--driver-java-options "-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///mnt1/mohit/log4j.properties"
--class com.myCompany.myMainClass 
myFat.jar
```

Why the behavior differs? How can I make `spark-submit` to use the packaged file?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you are referring to is intended for YARN, but you run on local mode.

Try specifying it as follows:

```
spark-submit 
--master local[1]
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=/mnt1/mohit/log4j.properties"
--class com.myCompany.myMainClass 
myFat.jar
```

Comment: thanks for correcting, but the issue still remains. Why its not possible to use packaged log4j properties?

Comment: Refer to this question for packaged log4j properties: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237662/log4j-properties-file-bundled-into-jar-in-spark-app-is-ignored